# Delete all duplicated rows except max value from python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database, that I am using from my Discord python bot with AIOMySQL, but I see that by error the bot created duplicated rows with the same ID but updated the values, and that last it's what I wanted. One example of my duplicated rows:

[duplicated rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17zic.png)

So now I want to delete all the duplicated rows, except the one with max XP.

I did a backup first, and then I was trying to save in a list all the IDs, except the ones that already are in the list. And then for every ID delete all except the max value. Like in this code:

```
await cur.execute("SELECT ID FROM USUARIOS;")
r = await cur.fetchall()
uslist = []
for a in r:
    for b in a:
        if b in uslist:
            pass
        elif b not in uslist:
            uslist.append(b)
for user in uslist:
    await cur.execute("SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE ID = {} ORDER BY XP LIMIT 1;".format(user))
    r = await cur.fetchone()
    uid = r[0]
    print(uid)
    xp = r[1]
    await cur.execute("DELETE FROM USUARIOS WHERE ID = {} and xp != {};".format(uid, xp))
    await conn.commit()
```

But when I saw the DB some rows were completelely deleted, including the max values.

Comment: you could do this for a huge database in one line of code using pandas, would you like me to show you how to do this? Or do you want to stick to your tags of mysql and sql?

Comment: i advice you to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "Help others reproduce the problem"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE XP <> (SELECT MAX(XP) FROM table) GROUP BY ID, XP, GC
UNION
SELECT * FROM table WHERE XP = (SELECT MAX(XP) FROM table)
```

Comment: `SELECT * ... GROUP BY ID, XP, GC` Basically this is abusing MySQL `GROUP BY` "feature".. Also this does not work on MySQL servers which have sql_mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` (like they should) active preventing bad written SQL queries like this one.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @RaymondNijland - grouping by all columns was the first thought I had for removing duplicates. Could you maybe share your approach to this problem? Would appreciate your inputs.

Comment: By using a window-function like ROW_NUMBER() and filtering thereafter, maybe..? I think windowing functions were implemented in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: "Could you maybe share your approach to this problem? Would appreciate your inputs" not going to answer on questions where there is bad example data (image).

Comment: "By using a window-function like ROW_NUMBER() and filtering thereafter, maybe..? " No a `DELETE` with a `JOIN` works just fine here without using `ROW_NUMBER()`